# What's the percentage of lose in the final step of Android In-App-Purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-pay, android-developer-api

I've an Android APP in Google Play store, with In-App-Purchase features. As the data I collected, there are 95% users cancelled their payment. What I mean is, assume 100 users init the process of Google Pay, only 5 of them finally done.

My question is, does that percentage make sense or not? What the average number for all Android APPs? What can I do to make it better?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think this is the right spot for this question. It's not exactly a specific programming question. An off hand thought is that either your purchase button is too hidden so users don't realize they are making the purchase or the purchase items don't live up to the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend reaching out to google for help with that.  95% walking away sounds high, but that is very dependent on your app in particular.  Unless you can get a large number of diverse app owners to divulge their data, google is the only entity with the measurement that might give you a realistic answer.